# Electron - when loading content in the main window and a BrowserVIew(), can main window content overlap the view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In Electron, I'm trying to create a custom menu and loading it into the main window, like so:

```
window = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false
})

window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/menubar.html`)
```

Then, I load external content into a `BrowserView()`, like so:

```
view = new BrowserView()

view.setBounds({
    x: 0,
    y: 32,
    width: window.getContentBounds()['width'],
    height: window.getContentBounds()['height'] - 32
})

view.webContents.loadURL(`[URL]`)

window.setBrowserView(view)
```

Now, the problem is that while I can see the menu bar, when I click on anything to open that menu it doesn't show because it's being covered by the BrowserView(). If I comment out/remove the `window.setBrowserView(view)` line, or even change the `x` bounds of the view (to something lower in the window), then I see the menu item just fine.

Is there a way to make the main window content overlap/overlay the browserview content?

Comment: No, you cannot do it with browserview.

Comment: @OJKwon am I stuck using <webview> then? Or multiple browserviews (which I haven't tried yet)?